# REST API Design: Should my response contain the input args for reference

Tags: rest, http, api-design

I am writing a simple Rest API. It will return a DB record on base of some input params. Example say my db contains {NewYork, Likes Pizza} for a key Jon.

So my input is like http://url/person?name="Jon".
This could return
1. {Jon, Newyork, Likes Pizza}
2. {Newyork, Likes Pizza}
 I am wondering if it is a good idea to return the input(Jon) as a field in response, just as a reference?

Answer (score 0):

REST is about resources and HTTP communication. It does not tell anything about how the response should look like and it’s totally up to you and your application.

Comment: I edited my question to explain more. Thanks for giving your comments. Could you please comment now, i suppose the question is better framed now.